# Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'Task_Board.Models.TaskModel'

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, casting

I am working on a program for my boss that creates a display for him to look at on a monitor when he comes to the IT office so he can quickly see what we are working on at a glance (similar to a scrum board).  So the 'Task_Board.Models.TaskModel' is a class that I created.  What I'm having trouble with is deleting the tasks from the database.  I have it working in another part of the code to delete a specific task, but when I try to delete all tasks by putting this logic into a loop then it throws the error above. Here is the method that works for a specific entity:

```
private void DoneDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var item = (TaskModel)DoneList.SelectedValue;
        TaskItem task = NinjectRepo.Instance.TaskItemRepo.Get(item.TaskId);
        NinjectRepo.Instance.TaskItemRepo.Remove(task);
        Update();
    }
    catch (Exception a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("System Message: " + a.Message, "ERROR");
    }
}
```

And this is the original troublesome code:

```
for (int i = ToDoList.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var item = (TaskModel)ToDoList.Items.GetItemAt(i);
    TaskItem task = NinjectRepo.Instance.TaskItemRepo.Get(item.TaskId);
    NinjectRepo.Instance.TaskItemRepo.Remove(task);
}
```

I tried to set the selected value in a different way in the code below, but it throws the same error.

```
for (int i = ToDoList.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    ToDoList.SelectedValue = ToDoList.Items.GetItemAt(i);
    var item = (TaskModel)ToDoList.SelectedValue;
    TaskItem task = NinjectRepo.Instance.TaskItemRepo.Get(item.TaskId);
    NinjectRepo.Instance.TaskItemRepo.Remove(task);
}
```

I don't understand what is happening between the method that works and the one that doesn't because it is basically the exact same logic is it not?

**EDIT:**
This is how I populate the lists:

```
items = NinjectRepo.Instance.TaskItemRepo.Get().OrderBy(q=>q.Rank).AsQueryable();
//update ToDo Lists
var tdlist = await items.Select(q => new TaskModel { TaskId = q.TaskId, Status = 
q.Status, Rank = q.Rank, Type = q.Type.Name, Assigned = q.Date, Description = q.Description })
     .Where(items => items.Status.ToLower() == ToDoStatus.ToLower()).ToListAsync();
ToDoList.ItemsSource = tdlist;
ToDoList.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
ToDoList.Columns[4].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: What is `ToDoList` and how is it different from `DoneList`?  My guess is the population/databinding is different between the two.

Comment: @Zer0 I updated the post to show how I populate the lists but both the ToDoList and DoneList are DataGrids that store 'TaskItem' objects. The only difference is which status the TaskItem's have (Ex: "ToDo" vs "Done")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem I was having actually was caused by the NewItemPlaceholder that is automatically added at the end of a DataGrid.  So when I tried to cycle through the DataGrid's items, when it came to converting the NewItemPlaceholder to a TaskItem it couldn't do it because there was no data in the row.  So to fix it I changed the DataGrid to read only in order to get rid of the extra row.